# Developer version of Android OS

Tags: android

I am trying to follow the link [Here at the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html) to check hierarchy viewer and pixel perfect tools. However the functionality I am checking is not possible to test on an emulator due to its limited capability. So my next target is a real device. However the document states: `To preserve security, Hierarchy Viewer can only connect to devices running a developer version of the Android system.` Now my next target is where to find the Developer OS and how to install it, is there any comprehensive guide for it or any resource, link which serves as a tutorial. Plus a source to download this particular OS? Also is it necessary to have a Google phone? Can't I use a simple android phone which does not come from Google?

Comment: What limitations are you running into? Maybe you can use a different (faster) emulator like [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/). And maybe that message only means you have to turn USB debugging on, did you try that?

Comment: Yes I usually test my code on my device itself but seems Hierarchy-Viewer requires the device to run a special OS. Also I am working with Google accounts and I as of now cannot add a Google account to my emulator for Data synchronization like "Events". Hey and thanks I am looking into what Genymotion has to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`To preserve security, Hierarchy Viewer can only connect to devices running a developer version of the Android system.` 
I would like to add **AND ON ROOTED DEVICES** and there are virtual devices like genymotion that does support hardware features like a real device. 
If you get a rooted phone you are done. No need to download any developer edition OS or anything. 
**AND FYI** 
**Developer edition devices are rooted devices with unlocked bootloader** and maybe some other facilities

Comment: Okay so a simple root will do!! Let me try my hands on that!

Comment: Yes. Simple root will do. And you can also have a look at https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer